# Access UIButton in a category of a UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am creating a simple category of `UIViewController` which adds the possibility to show a button simply on top of the view to display a chat window.

```
@interface UIViewController (ChatButton)
- (void)showChatButtonFromTop;
- (void)showChatButtonFromBottom;
- (void)hideButton;
@end
```

Now in the method I create a button and display it:

```
- (void)showChatButtonFromTop
{        
    UIButton* chatBtn = [self constructButtonWithWidth:buttonAxisSize X:buttonX Y:buttonY];
    [self.view addSubview:chatBtn];
}
```

But I also need to hide the button:

```
- (void)hideButton
{
    // confusion!  
}
```

How do I get that button? Categories don't allow for properties, so how do I store the reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you add the button to view, add a tag to button

```
chatBtn.tag = 1234;
[self.view addSubview:chatBtn];
```

when you try to hide the button access it's tag

```
- (void)hideButton
{
    UIButton *chatBtn = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:1234];
    [chatBtn setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: Of course, thanks. But is this a recommended way? Or am I doing something totally wrong?